# Theo Connection to Neo4J Broken After Update to Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, neo4j

I've been having a strange problem using the Theo framework to connect to my GraphStory Neo4J database after updating to Xcode 6.3. To quickly summarize the history of the error, I updated my Xcode to 6.3, only to find that Theo had a number of syntax error due to Swift 1.2. I fixed the syntactical errors, but received errors asking for a 'query' entry or just general connection errors. I quickly backpedaled, copied over my project, reinstalled my Theo submodule, installed Xcode 6.2, and launched an old version of my app, only to find the same problems:

```
Error Domain=com.theo.network.error Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.theo.network.error error -1011.)" UserInfo=0x174035bc0 {TheoResponse=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174036060> { URL: [MY URL] } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 564;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 10 Apr 2015 21:08:49 GMT";
    Server = "[MY SERVER]";
} }, TheoResponseCode=400, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey=The response was empty, but you received at valid response code}
```

I haven't changed any of the functions, and I've tried this with both the syntax-corrected version of Theo, and the original version with my old code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm also new to posting on Stackoverflow, so if I'm missing any important information in the question, please let me know and I'll gladly update the question.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this issue, because I'm having the same problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 400 status response from the server is often "bad query". Try lifting your queries out of the code and pasting them into the Neo4j browser, and run them there to check.

My expectation is that GraphStory has updated the Neo4j version, and there are occasionally queries that will break on new versions. In the Theo examples we had a now required parenthesis that was missing in our examples. (this is updated for the upcoming 3.0 release)